# PHP error - Constant DB_HOST already defined?

Tags: php

I am doing a little homework assignment in which we are making a very rudimentary CMS. We are to fill in a form containing title, body, permalink. The CMS then takes the permalink, and adds it to the main nav bar. When that permalink is clicked on the navbar, the title, content,  datestamp created and datestamp modified are to be displayed.

I have that stuff working, only problem is that when I click on the nav link,

I receive this notice:

> Notice: Constant DB_HOST already defined in C:\Program
>   Files\xampp\htdocs\php\assignment_6\config.php on line 2
>
> Notice: Constant DB_USER already defined in C:\Program
>   Files\xampp\htdocs\php\assignment_6\config.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Constant DB_PASS already defined in C:\Program
>   Files\xampp\htdocs\php\assignment_6\config.php on line 4
>
> Notice: Constant DB_NAME already defined in C:\Program
>   Files\xampp\htdocs\php\assignment_6\config.php on line 5

I have a config.php file that I use to establish a DB connection:

```
<?php
     define('DB_HOST','******');
     define('DB_USER','******');
     define('DB_PASS','******');
     define('DB_NAME','******');  

    $cms_db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

         if(!$cms_db){
          echo"Could not connect: ".mysql_error();
     } 
?>
```

Here is the code from the file calling `config.php` causing this notice:

```
<?php
   require('config.php');
   $perm = $_GET['p'];
   $query = "SELECT * FROM cms WHERE permalink = '$perm'";
   $result = $cms_db->query($query);
   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
   $page_title = $perm;
   require('header.php');
?>
<h1><?=$row['title'];?></h1>
<hr/><br/>
<p class="para"><?=$row['content']?></p>

<?php require('footer.php');?>
```

A small amount of simple code, but what is the problem? It is not a fatal error but it is annoying.

Comment: Could you check if there is more than one instance of the command:  `require('config.php');` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're probably including config.php multiple times. Check all your scripts and find this duplicity. You can use `require_once()` instead of `require()` to prevent this.

Comment: Funny, I figured that might be the issue, so I googled it and found the require_once. I tried it, and got the same issue. I will try it again.

Answer (score 2):

Do either header.php or footer.php include config.php?

If so thats your problem.

Comment: Yes, footer does, so I used require_once, to no avail. I will try again, 'cause I probably only think I did it....

Comment: Damn it, forgot one. You guys => win. 
Sucks when you kinda figure out the answer, implement it incorrectly, and then ask for help only to find out you were on the right track in the first place. Thanks alot. Sorry I can only pick one as the check mark.

Comment: I know this is old, but your question led me on the right track. Thanks for asking this. +1. :-)

Answer (score -2):

Either  header.php or footer.php or leftMenuBar include config.php?

If so, thats your problem..

Just remove (include config.php) line and you are done..

if u Dont want to mess functionality
just add the following line..
`error_reporting(0);`

after `include config.php` line!